# CSScript: Inject System.linq inside "CreateFunc"

Tags: c#, linq, cs-script

This code:

```
 func = CSScript.CreateFunc<int>(@"int f(int[] inputs) { return inputs.Max(); }");

 int max = func(new int[]{ 235,123,675,111 });
```

is throwing:

`error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I need to inject `System.Linq` inside my function "`func`"

....**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [CS-Script Documentation](http://www.csscript.net/help/using_.net_assemblies.html):

> Hints And Tips
>
> When you need to reference many assemblies (and particularly when these assemblies are commonly used) it is convenient to combine all //css_reference statements into single file containing no code and include this file into your primary script.
>
> The following code includes linq.includes.cs file containing references to all assemblies required for programming against LINQ:
>
> ```
> //css_include linq.includes.cs;
> using System;
>
> class Test 
> { 
>     static public void Main( string [] args)
>     {
>         ....
> ```
>
> This is the content of the linq.includes.cs file:
>
> ```
> //css_ref System.Core;
> //css_ref System.Data.ComponentModel;
> //css_ref System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
> //css_ref System.Xml;
> //css_ref System.Xml.Linq;
> ```

Comment: I dont understand this part: `it is convenient to combine all (..) into single file containing no code and include this file into your primary script.`

Comment: also... in the example they are creating a class, but in my question i'm creating only a function